# Not able to import tensorflow_datasets module in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tensorflow-datasets

[image]
I am trying tensorflow course from Udacity which uses google colab to write/run the code. But I want to run the code on my local machine and hence have created a new environment to run the code , but am unable to import tensorflow_dataset into the tensorflow environment .

I have tried searching for the module from the anaconda navigator to install it in tensorflow environment but anaconda navigator does not provide the tensorflow datasets module.

From cmd (command prompt) I tried to execute the below commands
1.activate tensorflow
2. pip install tensorflow_datasets

It says the module is installed but when I tried to import it from jupyter notebook I get error that there is no module with name tensorflow_datasets

1.activate tensorflow
2. pip install tensorflow_datasets

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-46a8a2031c9c> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'
```

And if I am trying to import from tensorflow env 
1.jupyter notebook
2.import tensorflow_datasets as tdfs

````
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-46a8a2031c9c> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\__init__.py in <module>()
     44 # needs to happen before anything else, since the imports below will try to
     45 # import tensorflow, too.
---> 46 from tensorflow_datasets.core import tf_compat
     47 tf_compat.ensure_tf_install()
     48 

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     16 """API to define datasets."""
     17 
---> 18 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BeamBasedBuilder
     19 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import BuilderConfig
     20 from tensorflow_datasets.core.dataset_builder import DatasetBuilder

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\core\dataset_builder.py in <module>()
     27 from absl import logging
     28 import six
---> 29 import tensorflow as tf
     30 
     31 from tensorflow_datasets.core import api_utils

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     30 

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HOME\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\HOME\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\HOME\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\HOME\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.```
````

Comment: Did you try importing in the cmd window itself?

Comment: Yes , still not working (Please look at the edited description)

Comment: Which version of python and tensorflow are you using?

Comment: From the error msg, I could infer that the installation of tensorflow is broken, i recommend you to delete the files related to tensorflow installation manually and install it again.When I tried installing it tensorflow_datasets and importing it worked for me..

Comment: Doing a clean install worked well  , the problem was that I have python 3.7 and python 2.7 installed and the directories got messed up. Tensorflow ran only on python 3.5 (I dont know if it runs only on 3.5)

Answer (score 34):

tensorflow_datasets is a separate module. You can install it using pip :

```
pip install tensorflow_datasets
```

Then you can import it as:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

Answer (score 7):

to use tensorflow-datasets in anaconda you have to use the below command

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-datasets
```

i tried using pip install and all but it was not working fine.but the above command worked like a charm.

using pip install will only install tensorflow-datasets in system python installation, which cant be used inside anaconda environment

Answer (score 2):

To use tensorflow datasets, open the terminal/command prompt and enter :

> **`pip install tensorflow_datasets`**

And if you are using Anaconda, you need to open up your environment and then manually import it as it doesn't gets installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having anaconda prompt, then as the answers already suggest installing tensorflow-datasets should work without issues. You can find the related Pypi package [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-datasets/). This installation should work in command prompt (with pip /python installed) as well.

```py
pip install tensorflow-datasets
```

If you are directly installing via conda, it is best to set up conda-forge as all the packages are shared in a single channel.Importantly the corresponding builds for AMD,Linux and MacOS are also up-to-date. For installing , here are the steps:

- Making sure conda version is >=4.9:

```py
conda --version
conda update conda
```

- Adding conda-forge as the highest priority channel:

```py
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

- Activate Strict priority (optional for Conda>=5.0):

```py
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

- Install the tensorflow-datasets package from conda-forge:

```py
conda install tensorflow-datasets==4.3.0
```

4.3.0 is the latest version as per Pypi.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anaconda, go to Anaconda Navigator -> Environments -> Choose your environment. After that simply find which package would you like to install and click it. After you accept it, it uploads automatically. It is really easy. (It took half an hour to find a correct answer for me, but after finding in Anaconda it is way easier than using Terminal) Do not forget to restart Anaconda after installing new packages.

Answer (score 1):

if somebody is getting error even after that like "No module named resources" use this code before importing tensorflow_datasets:
"pip install --upgrade tfds-nightly"