# Unexpected error message while installing Tensorflow Datasets package

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got an unexpected error message while trying to install TensorFlow datasets. I have TensorFlow 2.0 and also enabled eager execution.

Here's the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-66fff9018d39> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow_datasets

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation_wrapper.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    104     attr = getattr(self._dw_wrapped_module, name)
    105     if (self._dw_warning_count < _PER_MODULE_WARNING_LIMIT and
--> 106         name not in self._dw_deprecated_printed):
    107       if self._dw_module_name:
    108         full_name = 'tf.%s.%s' % (self._dw_module_name, name)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.autograph.experimental' has no attribute 'do_not_convert'
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Do you have the alpha version? It [seems like this might have been an issue there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163835/i-get-an-error-when-importing-tensorflow-datasets) and should be patched in 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Python and TF versions as it works fine when working with **Python>=3.6.7** , **Tensorflow==2.0** and **Tensorflow_datasets==1.2.0**

Try with these above versions.